# Computing a list of all possible combinations containing arbitrary n elements from a given list of elements

Tags: prolog

I am facing a problem in in how to write a program in Prolog that takes a list of elements and a size and returns a list of all possible combinations of the elements given the size.

Here is an concrete example to clarify the problem:

```
?- comb([a, b, c, d, e], 3, L).
L = [a,b,c] ;
L = [a,b,d] ;
L = [a,b,e] ;
...
```

As I am a newby to Prolog I would like to get some hints for solving this problem.

I intend to fix one element and then apply recursion to the rest of positions. But I am lacking an idea of how to realize this this.

Thanks in advance for your advices :)!

Comment: sorry but the question already raised does not address my current problem @lurker

Comment: I have reopened your question, but the point is, since you asked for hints, you can search this site for `[prolog] subset of list` and find plenty of ideas there for how to get started. If you want to constrain a list to length `N` you just use `length(List, N)`.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach is using a typical recursive pattern in Prolog.

There is a trivial base case in which the length is 0:

```
comb(_, 0, []).
```

This case says that if I have a length of 0, then the sublist is the empty list. This is true regardless of the full list, so we use `_` since we don't care what it is.

Recursively, you have two possible ways that the 3rd argument can be a sublist of length `N` of the first argument:

1. If I have a list `[X|Xs]` (first element is `X` and rest of the list is `Xs`) and a length `N`, then one condition is that `N > 0` since the 0 case is already taken care of. Also, a sublist `S` would look like `[X|T]` where `T` is a sublist of `Xs` and has length `N1` where `N1` is one less than `N`.
2. If I have a list `[X|Xs]` (first element is `X` and rest of the list is `Xs`) and a length `N`, then I would have the condition `N > 0` in this case as well, and the sublist `S` would be a sublist of `Xs` of length `N`. Since I don't care about `X` in this case, I can write it as `_`.

That describes, in words, what your predicate needs to do and suggests two predicate clauses. I took a different approach here than what I was first considering when I suggested, in my comment to your question, using the `length/2` predicate. In the above, you don't need to use that predicate.

**Extra Credit**

If you use CLP(FD), which is Prolog's way of reasoning with integers, you can easily obtain a more general solution using the above approach. In CLP(FD), you would use `N #> 0` instead of `N > 0`, and `N1 #= N - 1` instead of `N1 is N - 1`. Using this approach, you can get results such as this:

```
| ?- length(List, 3), comb(List, N, Sublist).

List = [_,_,_]
N = 0
Sublist = [] ? a

List = [A,_,_]
N = 1
Sublist = [A]

List = [A,B,_]
N = 2
Sublist = [A,B]

List = [A,B,C]
N = 3
Sublist = [A,B,C]

List = [A,_,B]
N = 2
Sublist = [A,B]

List = [_,A,_]
N = 1
Sublist = [A]

List = [_,A,B]
N = 2
Sublist = [A,B]

List = [_,_,A]
N = 1
Sublist = [A]

no
| ?-
```

Or this...

```
| ?- length(List, 5), comb(List, N, [a,b]).

List = [a,b,_,_,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [a,_,b,_,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [a,_,_,b,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [a,_,_,_,b]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [_,a,b,_,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [_,a,_,b,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [_,a,_,_,b]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [_,_,a,b,_]
N = 2 ? ;

List = [_,_,a,_,b]
N = 2 ? a

List = [_,_,_,a,b]
N = 2

no
| ?-
```